# Can I write $\frac {\partial E_{rs}} {\partial E_{mn}} = \delta_{rsmn}?$

Tags: tensors, kronecker-symbol

Can I write $\frac {\partial E_{rs}} {\partial E_{mn}} = \delta_{rsmn}?$ and then use that delta to change variables in another tensor like:

$$C_{ijkl}\delta_{rskl} = C_{ijrs}$$

or is there some other form of the delta. I wikipedia'd the generalized kronecker delta but I don't think it corresponds to the partial derivative above. I'm operating off of the fact that

$$\frac {\partial x_{i}} {\partial x_{m}} = \delta_{im}$$

Comment: Kronecker's delta is very useful to express logical conditions such as: $i=m$ or $i\neq m$. Now in order to encode multiple logical conditions: $(r,s)=(m,n)$, one may use products of two delta's. Try to understand what are the values of $\delta_{rs}\cdot \delta_{mn}$.

Comment: There's an important subtlety if $E_{rs}$ is (anti)symmetric.

Comment: You probably wanted this expression $$\frac{\partial E_{ij}}{\partial E_{mn}} = \delta_{im}\delta_{jn}$$